# How can I get Z-depth from unlit shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Currently, I try to make z depth effect as Image Effect, but result image is not correctly rendered. something wrong...

If I use standard shader (unity 5), result image was correctly rendered(z depth image is ok), but not unlit shader.

what happen? if you have any idea, tell me why.

#### shader

```
Shader "Custom/RenderDepth"
{
    Properties
    {
        _DepthLevel ("Depth Level", Range(1, 3)) = 2
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {

            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
            uniform fixed _DepthLevel;
            uniform half4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            struct uinput
            {
                float4 pos : POSITION;
                half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct uoutput
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            uoutput vert(uinput i)
            {
                uoutput o;
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, i.pos);
                o.uv = MultiplyUV(UNITY_MATRIX_TEXTURE0, i.uv);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(uoutput o) : COLOR
            {
                float depth = UNITY_SAMPLE_DEPTH(tex2D(_CameraDepthTexture, o.uv));
                depth = pow(Linear01Depth(depth), _DepthLevel);
                return depth;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

#### CS

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[RequireComponent (typeof(Camera))]
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera _cam;
    public Material mat;

    public float DepthLevel = 1.0F;

    void Start ()
    {
        _cam.depthTextureMode |= DepthTextureMode.Depth;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }

    void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        mat.SetFloat("_DepthLevel", DepthLevel);
        Graphics.Blit(source, destination, mat);
    }
}
```

[image: Standar Shader(Unity5)]

[image: Unlit Shader]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this solution. I use the SHADOWCASTER pass from the VertexLit legacy shader prior to render my unlit object.

Then your shader would look like this:

```
Shader "Custom/RenderDepth"
{
    Properties
    {
        _DepthLevel ("Depth Level", Range(1, 3)) = 2
    }
    SubShader
    {
        UsePass "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit/SHADOWCASTER"

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
            uniform fixed _DepthLevel;
            uniform half4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            struct uinput
            {
                float4 pos : POSITION;
                half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct uoutput
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            uoutput vert(uinput i)
            {
                uoutput o;
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, i.pos);
                o.uv = MultiplyUV(UNITY_MATRIX_TEXTURE0, i.uv);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(uoutput o) : COLOR
            {
                float depth = UNITY_SAMPLE_DEPTH(tex2D(_CameraDepthTexture, o.uv));
                depth = pow(Linear01Depth(depth), _DepthLevel);
                return depth;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a fallback option in the unlit shader so it can use the other needed passes  (depth/shadow/etc) from this fallback shader.

Adding the following line to your unlit shader should help.

```
Fallback "Diffuse"
```